# React: Passing local state to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I'm trying to create a reusable "Modal" component in React. The **Modal** component will have some input fields and a submit button and when user clicks the Submit button in the **Modal**. the modal should be closed and the data user entered in the input fields should be passed up to the parent component through a callback function declared in parent component. The code is working fine but i think(not sure) it's not the right solution as i had to create "React state" in both the Modal(child) component and the parent component where the Modal component is used. As you can see(sandbox code) the state is repetitive in both components and i was wondering how can i keep the state in only one place. My understanding is I'd definitely need to create a state in Modal component for the input fields to keep track of changes but i am not sure how can i use that data in parent component without creating same state

Here is a Sandbox that i created to show what i've done so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-matsumoto-1zl9b?file=/src/Modal.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not duplicate state I would enclose the inputs in the modal in a `form` element and convert the inputs to uncontrolled inputs. When the form is submitted grab the form field values and pass in the `formData` callback and reset the form. Explicitly declare the button to be `type="submit"`.

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const firstName = e.target.firstName.value;
    const lastName = e.target.lastName.value;

    props.formData({ firstName, lastName });
    e.target.reset();
  };

  if (!props.show) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="modal" id="modal">
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" />
          <input type="text" name="lastName" />
          <button className="toggle-button" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

[image: Edit react-passing-local-state-to-parent-component]

It seems the crux of your question is about the code duplication between your parent component and a modal. What I would really suggest here is to decouple the modal from any specific use case and allow any consuming parent components to pass a close handler and children components.

This keeps the state in the parent, and thus, control.

Example modal component:

```
const Modal = ({ onClose, show, children }) =>
  show ? (
    <div className="modal" id="modal">
      <button type="button" onClick={onClose}>
        X
      </button>
      {children}
    </div>
  ) : null;
```

Parent:

```
function App() {
  const [isShowModal, setIsShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState();
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState();

  const showModal = (e) => {
    setIsShowModal((show) => !show);
  };

  const closeModal = () => setIsShowModal(false);

  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const firstName = e.target.firstName.value;
    const lastName = e.target.lastName.value;

    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);

    e.target.reset();
    closeModal();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>First Name is : {firstName}</h2>
      <h2>Last Name is : {lastName}</h2>
      <button className="toggle-button" onClick={showModal}>
        Show Modal
      </button>
      <Modal show={isShowModal} onClose={closeModal}>
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" />
          <input type="text" name="lastName" />
          <button className="toggle-button" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-passing-local-state-to-parent-component (forked)]

Here it's really up to you how you want to manage the interaction between parent and modal content. I've shown using a form and form actions so your state isn't updated until a user submits the form. You can use form utilities (redux-form, formix, etc...) or roll your own management. Life's a garden, dig it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i liked this idea but asking just for my education. So is this a recommended way when we want to pass data from child to parent? also, why we need to set button type to be "submit"?

Comment: @learnbydoing I'd say it's recommended if you don't want to "duplicate" state, but to be honest, using controlled inputs isn't wrong either. What I would really go for would be to de-couple the modal container from its content. In other words, let a parent component pass (as children) the modal content and use the single state and handlers in the parent while the modal renders it. If this is something you're interested in I can add a demo. Well, button's by default are of `type="submit"` if you don't specify a type, but being explicit helps other devs.

Comment: that's really helpful for me, so looks like when we've parent child relationship and need to pass data upto the parent component from child, we should de-couple the child content from it's content and instead use {children} where children would be the actual content passed from it's parent? or if you could explain little bit more on when to use this strategy vs the one i used in my original post?

Answer (score 0):

You can define these states in your `App` component :

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
const [user, setUser] = useReducer(reducer, {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
});

const toggleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
};
```

And pass them through `props` when you render your Modal component :

```
<div className="App">
    <h2>First Name is : {firstName}</h2>
    <h2>Last Name is : {lastName}</h2>
    <button className="toggle-button" onClick={toggleModal}>
        Show Modal
    </button>
    <Modal
        show={showModal}
        hide={() => toggleModal(false)}
        user={user}
        updateUser={setUser}
    />
</div>
```

Then, in your Modal component, define states for `firstName` and `lastName` :

```
const Modal = (props) => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(props.user.firstName);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(props.user.lastName);

    const onFirstNameChange = ({ target }) => {
        setFirstName(target.value);
    };

    const onLastNameChange = ({ target }) => {
        setLastName(target.value);
    };
    
    // ...
}
```

And now you can submit changes like this from your `Modal` component :

```
const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    props.updateUser({
        firstName,
        lastName
    });
    props.hide();
};
```

[image: Edit react-passing-local-state-to-parent-component]

Comment: Thanks for your response, wondering what if i've 10-15 input fields in the "Modal" component, then looks like i'd need to pass same number of fields through props. Would that be a right approach?

Comment: Yes that's why in my codesandbox I used something different : I used `useReducer` hook, so it's better because we don't need to pass a new prop for every input field of the modal.

Comment: @learnbydoing I've made an edit to my post to show you the changes I've made.

Comment: i think you missed one thing from my original post, i intend to submit the modal data when clicking on submit button on Modal which needs to be visible on the parent component, but your implementation is updating the parent prop when we enter text in input fields, instead it should be passed to parent component only we submit through the submit button

Comment: Yes, I missed that. So I updated my post as well as the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-http-ul7ji?file=/src/App.js). Is it now what you expected ?